# How to make openflow switch capable of marking informations on the id field of ip packets?

Tags: c, opendaylight, sdn, mininet

I'm still a beginner in SDN and all that comes with it (openflow, mininet, opendaylight...) and so if I say a mistake, please excuse my ignorance.
So my request is about marking ip packets by openflow switches: I want to intercept packets coming to switches (by iptables that will send packets in a nfqueue queue) so that the switch can then mark them with its own information (identifier, distance from destination...) on the id field of an ip packet.... this information is then collected by the destination to reconstruct the path taken by the packet.
How can I enable a switch to mark packets like this? what commands should I execute? what language to implement the process? Where should I access it?
knowing that I have already implemented in C the marking process that works well in the traditional network (I tested it in a quagga router). can this code be useful to me for something in the mininet switches?
then if I don't use mininet, can OVS switch do the job? how?
Sorry, if I hadn't been more specific, but in anyway I'm here to answer any questions. I hope you can help me clear the way to get started.
Thank you.

Comment: @Shubha can you help please??

Comment: is it necessary in your case to use ODL or you can use any other SDN controller?

Comment: I have already started installing odl environment... but it is not necessary to use it .. i can use any other controller .

Comment: If you can use another controller then I can propose to use ryu controller. I am putting an answer for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [Ryu controller](https://osrg.github.io/ryu/) (a python based SDN controller). Regarding Queuing, packet marking and MPLS, you can check the **chapter 12 QoS** from the [Ryu Book](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/Ryubook.pdf). There are detailed examples there. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

if you manage your switches with OpenDaylight, then you don't want to use iptables.
you can use the openflowplugin to write flows to the switch to do all you want. I
think you can have a match-all kind of flow that will have the action you require
to "mark ip packets".